# Class Not Found exception with exec-maven-plugin when run on Linux

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am trying to run TestNG tests. My Project organization is - src->test->java->com->shn->library
The below command works well in Windows but fails in Linux.

```
mvn -X clean exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -e
```

Error Seen in Linux on running the same command -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project UAF: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project UAF: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Have you run `mvn install` on Linux to create the jar?

Comment: Yes, I did try mvn install

Comment: My Bad, I did run mvn install. But then, the command run by me was - mvn **clean** -X exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -e. So all the compiled classes were deleted & hence the error was apparent

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I ran -

```
mvn clean install.
```

Post which when I run -

```
mvn -X clean exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -e
```

The compiled classes get deleted & the error is apparent.

So the solution is -

```
mvn -X clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.shn.library.RunSuitesInParallel" -Dexec.classpathScope=test -e
```

Answer (score 24):

Though the accepted answer is fine, this might also help somebody.

It seems **you need to make sure you're building the Maven Project before running any plugin goals** that rely on the compiled classes.

In case when you create a new java class, By the time you going to use the plugin goal, `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown because there is no compiled version of that class (plugin rely on the compiled version of the class).

Just assume you have a plugin configuration like below in your pom.xml (*NOTE : original SO question it mentions about running the main class directly without specifying it in a pom.xml, and how to do it is explained in the accepted answer by [praneel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627448/praneel)*),

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
     <configuration>                 
         <mainClass>com.myproj.java.Main</mainClass>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So before you run any plugin goals,
do

```
mvn clean install
```

then

```
mvn exec:java
```

or do,

```
mvn install exec:java
```

Answer (score 19):

Most likely that the resolution to **ClassNotFoundException** when using **exec-maven-plugin**, is to **[change the default classpath scope](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-or-java-change-classpath-scope.html)** (src\main\java), to your **test classpath** (src\test\java).

It can be passed in the mvn command ( -Dexec.classpathScope="test" ), or in the pom.xml:

```
<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
```

for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>your.package.test.class</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        ...
                    </arguments>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

We were facing the same `ClassNotFoundException` issues when trying to use the `exec:java` plugin from Jenkins. Our compilation was occurring before usage of the plugin, but we were still seeing the exception:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ org.mycompany.myapp ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "org.mycompany.myapp.MyAppEntry"
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:610)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper (ClassLoader.java:945)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:873)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:246)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:825)
```

Inspecting the Jenkins workspace showed the class had been compiled as expected, so we were quite puzzled.

The issue turned out to be how the properties were being passed from Jenkins. We had added quotation marks in the "Properties" field of the Maven build step:

```
exec.mainClass="org.mycompany.myapp.MyAppEntry"
```

**The solution was to remove the quotation marks from Maven build step property config**:

```
exec.mainClass=org.mycompany.myapp.MyAppEntry
```