# ClassNotFoundException when running mvn exec:java on Windows

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am trying to run my program via the command line using Maven. The location of the class which starts everything off is `projectFolder -> src -> frogger -> game -> MainMenu.java`

I've tried running `mvn evec:java` and I am getting the following error:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: frogger.game.MainMenu
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.510 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-17T17:50:48Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project mainProject: An exception occured while executing the Java class. frogger.game.MainMenu -> [Help 1]
```

I've already tried running `mvn clean install` then `mvn exec:java` as suggested in this thread: [Class Not Found exception with exec-maven-plugin when run on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458243/class-not-found-exception-with-exec-maven-plugin-when-run-on-linux) but the issue still persists.

I've also tried running `mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="frogger.game.MainMenu"` which I found elsewhere but it gave me the same issue as above.

EDIT: Managed to fix it by rearranging my folder structure to match `src/main/java`

Comment: You need to compile it before you can `exec` it...

Comment: @Powerlord would that be with the ``mvn compile`` command? I've just tried the sequence of ``mvn clean install`` -> ``mvn compile`` -> ``mvn exec:java`` and still the same issue

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I have yeah, I think that + my folder structure were the two main problems but it's fixed and working now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
mvn -X clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="frogger.game.MainMenu"
```