# java maven class not found exception

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I built a server template in java and now i need to compile and run it using MAVEN.
this is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>bgu.spl</groupId>

<artifactId>spl-net</artifactId>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>


-<properties>

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<name>spl-net</name>

</project
```

When I run `mvn compile` it all works. but then i go to test it with: `mvn exec:java - Dexec.mainClass=”bgu.spl.net.impl.BGRSServer.ReactorMain” - Dexec.args=”<port> <No of threads>”` and it gives me a class not found exception. I looked in the target directory and this exact main was indeed there, it just refuses to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class Not Found exception with exec-maven-plugin when run on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458243/class-not-found-exception-with-exec-maven-plugin-when-run-on-linux)

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions but it did not help. It refuses to recognize the class even though it is there.

Comment: Did you try running `mvn install`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried the following:
```mvn clean install```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. I failed to realize that in ubuntu, the command: `mvn exec:java - Dexec.mainClass=”bgu.spl.net.impl.BGRSServer.ReactorMain” - Dexec.args=”<port> <No of threads>”` simply doesn't work. the correct command would be: `mvn exec:java - Dexec.mainClass=bgu.spl.net.impl.BGRSServer.ReactorMain - Dexec.args=<port> <No of threads>`